How do I hide the menu bar in a secondary window on Electron?
I have a JavaScript application running on Electron. I open a new window using window.open(). A new window pops up. However the menu bar at the top is shown (I have it hidden on the main window).
How do I hide this?
My complete code is
async function openWindow(){
    let file = await fs.readFile('datacard.html','utf8')
    let w = window.open()
    w.document.body.innerHTML = file
    return w
}

